# how to read the multiple sub tittle using xpath?

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

I want to read the top stories link from CNN news site using XPath in selenium. I gave my XPath as shown below.

```
text = ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="intl_homepage1-zone-1"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/article[1]/div/div[2]/h3/a/span[1]/strong")).getText();
```

It read only one sub heading, but I want to read the all the top stores heading how can I do that?

I know if i change the `article[2],article[3]...article[i]` it will read. Is there any way to read it using single XPath?

Answer (score 0):

The single **xpath** for fetching link of top stories is :

```
//div[contains(@data-analytics,'Top stories_list-hierarchical')]//h3[@class='cd__headline']/a/span[1]
```

You have to first store the elements in the list. For that, please use "**findElements**" not "**findElement**" as **findElement** will return only one element.

Then you can iterate over the list and print the text of all the Web Elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fetch all the webElements in the list using **findElements** and then you can iterate and read through all the links

```
List<WebElement> article_List= ieDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="intl_homepage1-zone-1"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/article");
for(WebElement article : article_List)
{
  String text = article.findElement("./div/div[2]/h3/a/span[1]/strong").getText();
}
```

In this way you can iterate over the whole list of headings.

P.S Try to use relative xpaths over absolute xpaths.

Hope this answer was helpful for you